# Firebase realtime database query for specific field

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to query a Firebase Realtime Database to find a users account based on their Email.

[image]

Here is how I am doing it currently with the User's ID obviously wrong when you don't know the ID.

```
const userData = (await UsersDatabase.ref(`/Users/oi73WHp4T8LUCgtZzesN`).once('value')).val();
```

How can I query all of the users to find the account with a specific email.

Here is what the JSON Response looks like:

```
{
   "userData":{
      "Account Created":1647458347685,
      "Date of Birth":"01/01/1901",
      "Email":"user@domain.com",
      "Gender":"male",
      "Name":"Test Account"
   }
}
```

Here is the updated response from this request:

```
     const userData = (await UsersDatabase.ref("Users").child("userData").orderByChild("Email").equalTo("test@domain.com"));
```

Here is the response in Postman:

```
{
    "userData": "https://domain.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/Users/userData"
}
```

All help is welcome!

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for your suggestion and answer below! I have added the JSON as the the query below did not work. If you have any other suggestions, I would be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: "did not work" is really hard to help with. Can you edit your question to show how you used the query, and what you did with the result. Ideally: include a `console.log` that outputs A, while you expected it to output B.

Comment: hi @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the query in my question and added the Postman response as console.log doesn't give anything of use. any ideas?

Comment: The code in your question doesn't load the data yet, but merely defines a query. You'll need to call `once`,`on` or `get` on it, just as you did in your original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, you are awaiting the `Reference` itself - not fetching its data:

```js
const userData = (await UsersDatabase.ref("Users").child("userData").orderByChild("Email").equalTo("test@domain.com"));
```

This line should be (fixed the query and shattered for readability):

```js
const userData = (
  await UsersDatabase.ref("Users")
    .orderByChild("Email") // <-- removed .child("userData")
    .equalTo("test@domain.com")
    .once('value') // <-- this was missing
).val();

/*
userData will be:

{
  "oi73WHp4T8LUCgtZzesN": { // <- this will be random
    "Account Created":1647458347685,
    "Date of Birth":"01/01/1901",
    "Email":"test@domain.com",
    "Gender":"male",
    "Name":"Test Account"
  }
}
*/
```

Although I would rewrite it like this to unwrap the data:

```js
const foundUsersQuerySnapshot = await UsersDatabase.ref("Users")
  .orderByChild("Email")
  .equalTo("test@domain.com")
  .limitToFirst(1)
  .once('value');

let userData = null;
foundUsersQuerySnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
  userData = { ...childSnapshot.val(), _key: childSnapshot.key };
  return true; // <- only return first entry
});

/*
userData will either be null (not found) or:

{
  "_key": "oi73WHp4T8LUCgtZzesN",
  "Account Created":1647458347685,
  "Date of Birth":"01/01/1901",
  "Email":"test@domain.com",
  "Gender":"male",
  "Name":"Test Account"
}
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try that now and let you know if it works!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the email address is stored in the `Email` property, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) to find the correct child node of `Users` with:

```
UsersDatabase
  .ref("Users")
  .orderByChild("Email")
  .equalTo("user@domain.com")
```

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it did not work. I have added the JSON response to my answer and am still a bit unsure as how to get this to work.

Comment: `  const userData = (await UsersDatabase.ref("Users").child("userData").orderByChild("Email").equalTo("test@domain.com"));`